# How to keep UTF-8 encoding when sorting JSON with jq

Tags: json, powershell, encoding, utf-8, jq

I'm using jq 1.5 on Windows PowerShell to sort the fields of a JSON file in an alphabetically order.

This works quite fine so far but special characters (like ÜÄÖüäö) are not kept in the jq output.

The original file is saved in UTF-8 encoding:

```
{
  "sha": "18879fb99367924cd76d402e841155bf73c8afb3",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
    "name": "John Doe ÜÄÖ",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "date": "2017-11-23T07:51:22Z"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the jq output saved as UTF-8:

```
{
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "date": "2017-11-23T07:51:22Z",
      "email": "john@example.com",
      "name": "John Doe ???"
    }
  },
  "sha": "18879fb99367924cd76d402e841155bf73c8afb3"
}
```

As you can see the characters ÜÄÖ are not recognized and are saved as ???.

This is how I use jq in PowerShell:

```
$json = Get-Content .\json.txt -Encoding UTF8
$jsonSorted = $json | .\jq-win64.exe --sort-keys '.'
Set-Content jsonSorted.txt -Value $jsonSorted -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: As recommended in the answer by peak changing the code page `chcp 65001` in PowerShell fixed this issue.

But further more I also had to change the call to the jq executable:

`$jsonSorted = .\jq-win64.exe --sort-keys '.' json.txt`

So it's not necessary to use the Get-Content cmdlet anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t mention which version of jq you are using, but I strongly suspect you have encountered a bug which has since been fixed. I believe the most recent UTF-8 bug was fixed by
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1317
in late January. Unfortunately, this means that for a fix, you’ll most likely need a version of jq more recent than 1.5.

Since you are using Windows, I would suggest looking at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor

#### Code Page

Maybe changing the code page will help? At the command prompt, first run `chcp` to ascertain the current code page; if it is not already 65001, run `chcp 65001`.

See also https://superuser.com/questions/237081/whats-the-code-page-of-utf-8

#### Verification on a Mac

```
$ file john-doe.json
john-doe.json: UTF-8 Unicode text

$ cat  john-doe.json
"John Doe ÜÄÖ"

$ jq --version
jq-1.5

$ jq . john-doe.json
"John Doe ÜÄÖ"

$ jqMaster --version
jq-1.5rc2-250-g239278f

$ jqMaster . john-doe.json
"John Doe ÜÄÖ"
```

Comment: I'm using version 1.5. I will check out Appveyor and take a look if it fixes my issue.

Comment: I downloaded the latest build from [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/stedolan/jq) but I still encounter the same issue.


`.\jq.exe --version
jq-1.5rc2-250-g239278f`

Comment: Please see updates.  At least you now have the best jq there is :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The version itself was not the problem. I think that the Get-Content cmdlet somehow makes problems here. Setting the file input directly to jq, like you do in your verification, works fine with both versions on my machine, too.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I save the output of jq in a variable the output looks like this:

`"name": "John Doe ├£├ä├û"`

Answer (score 7):

I tried everything mentioned here and still got incorrect output. I had to set `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` in PowerShell and then it works as expected. That's actually the only thing I had to do.